# verify list box value is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a list box (i.e., select tag), and I want to verify that atleast a single value is been selected, using jQuery

I have included jQuery and jQuery Validate plugin

Anyone have solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both the [`required`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required) and [`minlength`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength) rules here, for example:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    selectName: { 
      required: true,
      minlength: 1 
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the "selected" selector and checking it for null/undefined:

```
 if($("#ListBox1 > option[@selected]") != null)
 {
    //whatever code you need
 }
```

Comment: The `@attr` selector syntax was deprecated in jQuery 1.3 :)